# ngx-translate/core: instant method returns object instead from default lang

Tags: angular, angular7, ngx-translate

Language fallback not working for Spanish user when user, rather it is showing [object Object] as the translated value

**Scenario:**

en.json

```
"USER" : "User"
```

es.json

```
"USER" : {
  "COMPANY" : "Miembro"
  "VENDOR" : "Vendedor"
}
```

fr.json:

```
"USER" : {
  "DEFAULT": "Consommateur"
  "COMPANY" : "Membre"
  "VENDOR" : "Vendeur"
}
```

**Usage:**

```
{{ 'USER' | envlabel }}
```

**envlabel:** A pipe which will translate by checking user type

**Explanation:**

- For en user: it should always show "User" as the translated label
- For es user: it should show "Miembro" if the user type is company or
  "Vendedor" if user type is vendor or "User" for any other type
- For fr user: it should show "Membre" if the user type is company or
  "Vendeur" if user type is vendor or "Consommateur" for any other type

**Implementation:**

- We have logic for each steps to check with "USER.${TYPE}" type and if
  not found we remove type and just translate with "USER".
- Where for spanish user: "USER.COMPANY" and "USER.VENDOR" will work,
  but "USER.DEFAULT" will not work.
- So we do translate using "USER" which returns object from "es.json"
- This was returning "User" from "en.json" in "angular-translate"
  rather than the object from "es.json"

**Fix for now:** To make it work, we change language by use(defaultLang) and get the translated string and again use(userLang) after that before returning the translated text.

Comment: When the user changes the language, you need to call `TranslateService.use(currentLang)` for ngx-translate to change the defaultLang. So you "fix for now" is the current implementation I guess.

Comment: Thats what TranslateService.setDefaultLang does. check [this](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#2-init-the-translateservice-for-your-application).

Comment: use() function set currentLang for fallback if the translation not found in the user language file. For default langulage we use setDefaultLang(). Where as fix for now we use to change the user language to 'en' so ngx-translate won't look for in "es" it will check only in en file

Comment: So when the user changes, how are you initimating the ngx-tranlate to use the selected lang?

Comment: After user login, i'm setting the current language with use() and setting default by setDefaultLang(). The above scenario is when we want translation with type of user, where we use different pipe called "envlabel" with TranslateService instant method.